# Я написал код, но когда его запускаю, приложение крашится, не понимаю почему

Tags: java, android, android-studio

вот код:

```
package com.talk.talktools;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.Locale;

public class ttsactivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{private Button button;
    private EditText editText;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private TextToSpeech mTTS;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ttsactivity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        mTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    int result = mTTS.setLanguage(new Locale("ru"));

                    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                            || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                        Log.e("TTS", "Language not supported");
                    } else {
                        button.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("TTS", "Initialization failed");
                }
            }
        });

        View.OnClickListener Oclbutton = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = editText.getText().toString();
                mTTS.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

            }
        };

        button.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) Oclbutton);
    }

    public ttsactivity(FloatingActionButton fab) {
        this.fab = fab;
        setTitle("Talk&Tools");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ttsactivity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вообще надо в вопросе привети лог ошибки и указать строку её возникновения. А так - у вас конструктор объявлен непонятный. А в активити конструкторы нельзя использовать - удалите его. И поименуйте класс с большой буквы и камелКейсом - иначе код нечитаем.

Comment: Лог ошибки в студию